# java- I got wrong results of counting

Tags: java

I wrote a program which counts the number of rooms for each class (art, sport, etc).

For example, each class contains a maximum of 3 students. If I have 9 students, with 6 music students and 3 art students,the results have to be: 1 room for art and 2 rooms for music.

When I run the code, I get these wrong results: the number of rooms for art equals 2 instead of 1 and the number of rooms for music equals 1 instead of 2.

**Here is the result of execution of this program:**

```
Insert numbers of participants:

9
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
The number of rooms for Music is:1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
2
Insert student in class:
2
Insert student in class:
2
The number of rooms for Art is:2
```

**This is my code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GroupActivity
{ 
    public static void main()

    {
      Scanner GActivity=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Insert numbers of participants:");
      int participantNo= GActivity.nextInt();//Insert numbers of participants


      int music= 1;int art=2; int theatre= 3; int sport= 4; // Representation of each class by numbers.
      int countM=0; //This variable contains the number of the participants in music class.
      int countA=0; //This variable contains the number of the participants in art class.
      int countT=0; //This variable contains the number of the participants in theatre class.
      int countS=0; //This variable contains the number of the participants in sport class.
      int countOFR=0;

      for(int i=0;i<participantNo;i++)
      {
             System.out.println("Insert student in class:");
             int p= GActivity.nextInt();// // Representation of student by number.int 



             if(p==music)
             //for(
             {
                countM++;
                int M=countM;
                //System.out.println("student in class:"+music);
                //System.out.println("Total music class:"+M);
                    if(M==3)
                    {
                    countOFR++;
                    int countOfRoom=+countOFR;
                    System.out.println("The number of rooms for Music is:"+countOfRoom);
                    }

             }
              else if(p==art)
             {
                countA++;
                int A=countA;
               // System.out.println("student in class:"+art);

                    if(A==3)
                    {
                    countOFR++;
                    int countOfRoom=+countOFR;
                    System.out.println("The number of rooms for Art is:"+countOfRoom);
                    }
                //System.out.println("Total student in art class:"+A);


             }

             else if(p==theatre)
             {
                countT++;
                int T=countT;
               // System.out.println("student in class:"+theatre);
                //System.out.println("Total thaetre class:"+T);
                  if(T==3)
                    {
                    countOFR++;
                    int countOfRoom=+countOFR;
                    System.out.println("The number of rooms for Theatre is:"+countOfRoom);
                    }

            }
             else{
                countS++;
                int S=countS;

                if(S==3)
                    {
                    countOFR++;
                    int countOfRoom=+countOFR;
                    System.out.println("The number of rooms for Sport is:"+countOfRoom);
                }

                //System.out.println("Total sport class:"+S);
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: To make your code easier, you could get the count of rooms after you process the total by division instead of incrementing a counter and use if/else. Also, you could make the room calculation in a method and not repeat the calc. logic, imagine if you have 50 classes how long this code would be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `countOFR`. You are using this to store the no of rooms for all classes, instead of any one. Thus when you read data for class, the older value of `countOFR` gets added.

```
            if(M==3)
            {
            countOFR++;   // This should not be common for all
            int countOfRoom=+countOFR;
            System.out.println("The number of rooms for Music is:"+countOfRoom);
            }
```

instead use different variables

```
int countOFR_music = 0;
int countOFR_art = 0;
int countOFR_theatre = 0;
int countOFR_sport = 0;
```

then use it like this

```
            if(M==3)
            {
            countOFR_music++;   // This should not be common for all
            int countOfRoom=+countOFR_music;
            System.out.println("The number of rooms for Music is:"+countOfRoom);
            }
```

likewise for arts class

```
                if(A==3)
                {
                countOFR_art++;
                int countOfRoom=+countOFR_art;
                System.out.println("The number of rooms for Art is:"+countOfRoom);
                }
```

Comment: Hi aid exactly what you suggest, it doesn't work. I insert 9 participants into music class. The results of execution are:Insert numbers of participants:
9
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
The number of rooms for Music is:1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Insert student in class:
1
Further, i like to claer that i want to count the number of room by the end of devision to classes, by using in: if/else/while/for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much shorter code:

```
public class GroupActivity
{ 
    public static void main()

    {
      Scanner GActivity=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Insert numbers of participants:");
      int participantNo= GActivity.nextInt();//Insert numbers of participants


      int music= 1;int art=2; int theatre= 3; int sport= 4; // Representation of each class by numbers.
      int[] counts = new int[4]; //This variable contains the number of the participants in music, arts, theatre and sports classes in its 4 cells.

      for(int i=0;i<participantNo;i++)
      {
             System.out.println("Insert student in class:");
             int p= GActivity.nextInt();// // Representation of student by number.int 
             if(p<=4)
                 counts[p-1]++;
      }

      System.out.println("The number of rooms for Music is:" + Math.ceil(counts[music-1]/3.0));
      System.out.println("The number of rooms for Art is:" + Math.ceil(counts[art-1]/3.0));
      System.out.println("The number of rooms for Theatre is:" + Math.ceil(counts[theatre-1]/3.0));
      System.out.println("The number of rooms for Sports is:" + Math.ceil(counts[sport-1]/3.0));

    }
}
```

Comment: Plesae note that by convention, variable names in java begin with a small letter. So, you should rename `GActivity` to `gactivity`.

Comment: Your idea is same as mine. Yet, be careful, your array is just 4 but using `p` (may be 4) as an index. It will lead to an `OutOfBoundException`. To fix it, use `new int[5]` or use zero-base index (I prefer second way)

Comment: @TuTran - you are absolutely right! Updated my code to handle the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should count students on each class, then process them at the end.

First, declare one or more object to hold number of student. Your declaration could work fine, but to shorten your code, you should use an array:

```
int numOfStudent[] = new int[4]; // 4 is for 4 types of class
```

Then in the for loop, do a check before increase counter, may be ask use input again (it's up to you):

```
// ...
int p= GActivity.nextInt();
int idx = p - 1; // Convert to zero-base index
if (idx >= 0 && idx < numOfStudent.length()) {
    numOfStudent[idx]++;
}
```

Finally, out of for loop, just process them. Because each class contains maximum 3 student, we have:

```
int numOfMusicClass = (int)Math.ceil(numOfStudent[music - 1] / 3.0);
// ... Do the same for other class
```

Hopefully, this solution help you!

In addition, your class type is defined by number, thus, you should print out what number represents. For example:

> Insert student in class (1 - music, 2 - art, 3 - theatre, 4 - sport):

It will make user aware what he/she input.

Answer (score -2):

Write smaller functions. This is too big to read.

Comment: This should go as a comment.

Comment: this is not an answer.